# Shell Script reading metadata of a file and then mv each to a new directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel, perl, file-metadata

I'm using **RHEL7** on my Server, and I have a directory containing thousands of myriads of mixed `.mp3` files and I need a script helping me to clean up that chaos.

Let’s pretend 10 of my songs are for Miley Cyrus, 10 are for Ed Sheeran, 10 for Beethoven, 10 for Mozart and etc. All mp3 files are holding a numeric file name like `000.mp3`, `001.mp3`, and etc.

Now I want to write a script to read **metadata** of all those `.mp3` files, and `mv` each file to a new created directory by the name of the singer. Ed Sheeran’s to Ed Sheeran directory.

How can I have this by writing a shell script, or perl script?

Comment: Someone already did this: http://search.cpan.org/~jv/mp3rename/script/mp3rename

Comment: @Rahul Nothing that perfect in fact, I just know how to use `find` to locate all my `.mp3` files. I know we have some packages on Ubuntu, but I don't know what I can do on RHEL.

Comment: @IporSircer No that couldn't help. Mp3rename doesn't exist on RHEL7, like mp3info. BTW, I need a script, I need more detail. I'll be so grateful if you can help me that way. Thanks by the way.

Comment: mp3rename is a cpan module, and redhat also has perl-cpan. https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=perl-CPAN
It is a script.

Comment: @IporSircer Oh my bad, yes you're right, thanks. I will check if I can do what I'm looking for with it or not. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `exiftool`:

```
exiftool '-Directory<Artist' ./*.mp3
```

Recursively:

```
exiftool -ext mp3 '-Directory<$Directory/$Artist' -r .
```

Comment: It works like a magic, Thanks a million